# Update value of dictionary after iterating through list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tuples

I have the following:

```
tup_list=[("name1",2,3),("name6",54,6),("name4",4,6)]

my_dict={"name1": 0,"name2": 0,"name3": 0,"name4": 0,"name5": 0,"name6": 0}


def checker(tup_list,my_dict):
    for tup in tup_list: 
       if tup[0] in my_dict: 
          my_dict[0]+=1
```

I am looking to loop through tup_list, and if the key exists in my_dict, I want to add +1 to the value associated with that key in my_dict. I am getting errors and I am not sure how best to fix this.

Comment: Your question is not really clearly stated. Furthermore you should format your code.

Comment: It sounds as though you are looking for someone else to loop through this list... what have you tried?

Comment: So.. any attempts or code you've written so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"I am getting errors" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error Because when you do :

```
for tup in tup_list: 
   if tup[0] in my_dict: 
      my_dict[0]+=1  #first check what you are increasing
```

Try to `print(my_dict[0])` are you getting what you were expecting?

So you are increasing the value but where are you storing that changed stuff? For that, you have to tell dictionary to save that updated value  of which key.

instead of :

```
  my_dict[0]+=1
```

Use:

```
my_dict[tup[0]]+=1
```

or

```
my_dict[item[0]]=value+1   #if you are iterating over dict
```

Try this

```
def checker(tup_list,my_dict):
    for tup in tup_list:
        if tup[0] in my_dict:
            my_dict[tup[0]]+=1
    return my_dict

print(checker(tup_list,my_dict))
```

> Detailed solution:

```
tup_list=[("name1",2,3),("name6",54,6),("name4",4,6),]

my_dict={"name1": 0,"name2": 0,"name3": 0,"name4": 0,"name5": 0,"name6": 0}


    def checker(tup_list,my_dict):
        for item in tup_list:
            for key,value in my_dict.items():
                if item[0]==key:
                    my_dict[item[0]]=value+1
        return my_dict

print(checker(tup_list,my_dict))
```

output:

```
{'name4': 1, 'name3': 0, 'name6': 1, 'name5': 0, 'name1': 1, 'name2': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you. this helps a lot!